# how to list authorized AD group and users on CentOS 8

Tags: centos

We have one CentOS 8 server where it's integrated with Windows AD so users access it with their Windows credentials. I have a request and need to check out which users and groups are allowed to access it (not all the AD users were authorized). I can check on sudoers file to see who has the rights to run commands, but is there any other place we can check who can ssh to the server? /etc/passwd seems not storing the AD user info.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The other place where you can check who can login in to the machine is `/etc/sssd/sssd.conf` file. There you can find records like:

```
simple_allow_groups
filter_groups
```

and so on

Comment: There is also `/etc/security/access.conf` and because he wants to find who can SSH, `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.

Comment: @NasirRiley, not sure, because we talk about AD groups and usually configs you mention deal with local groups.

Comment: `/etc/security/access.conf` can include AD groups and `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` can be set to authenticate via AD or any other LDAP authentication source. That is how it is configured where I work and has been that way for years. I'm sure that we aren't the only ones.